# Exclude parameter does not work in dotnet test command with test coverage

Tags: c#, .net, testing, test-coverage, coverlet

I got project structure :

-my-application.sln
--src
----Api
----ApplicationServices
----Domain
----Infrastructure
--tests
----ApplicationServices.UnitTests
----Domain.UnitTests
----Infrastructure.UnitTests

with assemlby names : 
MyApp.CarModule.Api 
MyApp.CarModule.ApplicationServices
MyApp.CarModule.Domain
MyApp.CarModule.Infrastructure

I'm trying to run command for dotnet test with coverlet and exclude domain project

```
dotnet test /p:CollectCoverage=true /p:Exclude="[MyApp.CarModule.Domain.*]*"
dotnet test /p:CollectCoverage=true /p:Exclude="[Domain.*]*"
dotnet test /p:CollectCoverage=true /p:Exclude="[Domain]*"
dotnet test /p:CollectCoverage=true /p:Exclude="[*]Domain"
```

But still got same result for all combinations, that domain is included in my modules in results...

```
dotnet test /p:CollectCoverage=true /p:Exclude="[*]*"
```

Only above works but it exclude all projects from my results... so there is some problem with my assembly name...

How I should pass this assembly name to exclude parameter?

Comment: Maybe this might help you 

1. https://github.com/coverlet-coverage/coverlet/blob/master/Documentation/MSBuildIntegration.md#source-files

2. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-test#filter-option-details

3. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/testing/selective-unit-tests?pivots=mstest